# How can I change the background colour of backend list rows in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm trying to change the colour of backend list rows using listInjectRowClass in the controller but it's not fully working. It seems the default CSS is setting the colour of the table cells in alternate rows so the class that is applied to the row has no effect. Is there a workaround?

Comment: can you share what html it produces and what css you are adding. so we can help you

Comment: In the `listInjectRowClass` I return the `danger` class for any row that has expired. This gives me `<tr class="danger rowlink">` for any expired row. There is however the following line in storm.css: `table.table.data tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {background-color:#ecf0f1}` which is more specific.

Comment: hmmm..  css side what you are writing you need to write more specific 
like `table.table.data tbody tr.danger { background:red;}` there or at last resort you can use `!important;`